# Cannot find name 'DirectionConfig' in SAP Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to add RTL configuration in my SAP storefront. While implementing the configurations I am getting the error

> Cannot find name DirectionConfig

and

> Cannot find name DirectionMode

How to resolve this? Also, give some input to change the language and direction on clicking a change language button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? Since 2.1, these configuration are added to the public api of the storefront library. You should be able to import them, using:

```js
import {
  DirectionConfig,
  DirectionMode
} from '@spartacus/storefront';
```

The docs on directionality can be found at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/directionality/. This documentations states that

> In Spartacus, the direction of the UI reflects the active language

This means, that whenever the language is changed, the new (active) language will be used in the directionality logic.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do have version 2.1 only. The problem is with my Visual Studio Code. After restarting my VS Code it is working fine.

Comment: cool, I have do have that often as well, often if I switch branches. I use the "Reload Window" in vscode to reset the behaviour.